# Cocatenate two fields in ag-grid (Using VueJS)

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, ag-grid

I'm using ag-grid with VueJS (2) via https://www.ag-grid.com/best-vuejs-data-grid/#gsc.tab=0 and so far so good. I can populate a simple grid using a json based data store etc.

Ok, now part of my data source looks like this

```
"closingDate": "2017-05-16T23:00:00",
  "salaryDetails": {
    "paymentSchedule": "hourly",
    "minSalary": 150,
    "maxSalary": 200
  },
 "contractType": "contract",
 "numberOfPositions": 3,
```

I'd like to populate an ag-grid such that the contents of a MinSalary column looks like **"150 hourly"** (eg minSalary + ' ' + paymentSchedule)

Below is how I create my columnDefinition but as you can see I have no idea what expression to use for **field:** to achieve what I want.

```
 createColumnDefinitions: function () {
        return [
            { headerName: 'Min Salary', field: ???? }
        ]
 }
```

Any ideas?

Edit: What I want to know is, is it possible to do what I want to do from within my columnDefinition function? eg something like...

```
createColumnDefinitions: function () {
  return [
    { headerName: 'Min Salary', field: this.concatenateStuff(????) }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Why not manipulate your data into the format you want before it goes to the grid?

Comment: why can't you just do `salaryDetails.minSalary + " " + salaryDetails.paymentSchedule`? I'm not sure what the exact problem you're having is.

Comment: Because that doesn't work inside a columnDefinition expression

Answer (score 0):

Got it!

Turns out the solution was to use a "valueGetter" instead of "field" inside my columnDefinition.

So for me the column definition needs to be something like

```
{ 
headerName: 'Min Salary', valueGetter: 
  function (params) { return params.data.salaryDetails.minSalary + ' ' +     params.data.salaryDetails.paymentSchedule } 
}
```